# How to uniquely identify a contact on ContactsContract.Contacts table

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have an app that gets the `ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY` of a contact on the device and saves it on the app Db.

After reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY) page I thought I could use the `LOOKUP_KEY` to uniquely identify a contact, even when a contact is edited (for example after editing the name of the contact).

Actually I saw that after editing a contact, its `LOOKUP_KEY` changes, so I cannot use anymore the `LOOKUP_KEY` I saved on my app DB.

My question is: is there a way to uniquely identify a contact on `ContactsContract.Contacts` from when it is created for the first time on the device until it is deleted from the device?

Thank you

Comment: Might you be able to give a solution by example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `LOOKUP_KEY` is not meant to be used as a key on its own, instead it should be used together with a contact's `_ID` to form a full `lookupUri`.

The `lookupUri` can then be used to find a contact in `CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` tables.
The `CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` basically first looks for the contact by `_ID`, if it fails to find it, or the `_ID` seems like the wrong contact, it uses **hints** from the `LOOKUP_KEY` part to try and track down the correct contact for you.

From [`CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI)

> A content:// style URI for this table that should be used to create
>   shortcuts or otherwise create long-term links to contacts. This URI
>   should always be followed by a "/" and the contact's LOOKUP_KEY. It
>   can optionally also have a "/" and last known contact ID appended
>   after that. This "complete" format is an important optimization and is
>   highly recommended.
>
> As long as the contact's row ID remains the same, this URI is
>   equivalent to CONTENT_URI. If the contact's row ID changes as a result
>   of a sync or aggregation, this URI will look up the contact using
>   indirect information (sync IDs or constituent raw contacts).
>
> Lookup key should be appended unencoded - it is stored in the encoded
>   form, ready for use in a URI.

From [`getLookupUri(long contactId, String lookupKey)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri(long,%20java.lang.String))

> Build a CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI lookup Uri using the given _ID and
>   LOOKUP_KEY.

From [`LOOKUP_KEY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY)

> An opaque value that contains **hints** on how to find the contact if its
>   row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

Comment: So the best way to identify a contact is by what you get from `getLookupUri`? and not "lookupKey" that is passed to it, right, as the question says?  Supposed I wish to have a DB that has extra information about each contact, should I have the "lookupUri", or actually the "lookupKey"&"contactId" (that together I can make the "lookupUri" from them ?  And how does it know when "the _ID seems like the wrong contact" ?

Answer (score 0):

The row id (primary key) for each contact called `_ID`.

Comment: dont do this, whenever the user reimports their contacts they get new ids